# Application gets error when publishing in play store even given correct min and max sdk

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am trying to publish my xamarin forms app in playstore but it is not allowing upload apk.It is throwing below error:

> Your app currently targets API level 11 and must target at least API level 26 to ensure it is built on the latest APIs optimized for security and performance. Change your app's target API level to at least 26

but I have given min and target sdk in my xamarin tool.

I am stuck from last 3 days kindly reply your solution as soon as possible.

`<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" />`

[image: playstore error]
[image: min and max sdk set]
[image: set compiled sdk]

Answer (score 0):

Right click to the Android Project -> (Build) Android Application -> Setup here Minimum Android Version and Target Android Version for your app.

Inside AndroidManifest.xml after setup you find this

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="23" android:targetSdkVersion="26" />
```

For your info

> Google Play requirements for 2019
>
> In order to provide users with the best Android experience possible,
> the Google Play Console will continue to require that apps target a
> recent API level:
>
> August 2019: New apps are required to target API level 28 (Android 9)
> or higher.
>
> November 2019: Updates to existing apps are required to
> target API level 28 or higher.